# Switching nodes no refresh AJAX

Tags: 7, views, nodes, ajax

What I have is a view that shows couple of nodes of type "product", they are related by an SKU ID.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to switch between those related product produced by the view without refreshing the page.

Checking "Use Ajax" in my view did not achieve what I want.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have developed module [ajax_links_api](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) which help you to load any drupal page to a specified div with help of JQuery Ajax.

in your tpl =>

```
    <?php  l_ajax($title, $path, $target)  ?>
```

*$title: Title.*

*$path : Drupal path.*

*$target (optional):* ID or CLASS of DIV to be replaced. Default value is .region-content, you can change default value in admin page 'admin/settings/ajax_links_api'

**Example :**

```
<?php l_ajax("Load node 1", "node/1", ".region-content") ?>
```

Hope you can use this for this case